# input focus closes keyboard, requires long touch

Tags: javascript, ios

In my web view I programmatically create an input field element(using javascript). And then set focus to it after creation. The input element gets created on screen, and then when it goes to focus that element, the keyboard pops up for a split second and then closes. If i then single click into the input field to manually focus it, it won't grab focus. I have to manually hold the input field for a second in order for focus to hold. However, sometimes it works just by single clicking on it. Im get varying results. Is there some sort of propagation or something?

Ive even throw a bunch of input fields up. Some will focus and some won't without a LONG touch..

Am i missing something here?
This is iOS web view.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out the problem was with ngTouch in the angular framework.

Comment out line 358

// Blur focused form elements
event.target && event.target.blur && event.target.blur();

Solved the problem for me